# How can I read config file again and update prefix for Discord bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js, fs

I'm having some trouble coding prefix changing in my Discord bot. I've got all the basic functionality working:

- The prefix is saved in a config file
- The bot can write to the file and save it for later use

However, I can't seem to get the bot to use the new prefix after it's changed until I restart the bot. The config file shows that the prefix has been changed, but the bot doesn't respond to it.

So, my question is either, how can I refresh the memory so that the config is reloaded, or how can I get the bot to read my config again and use the new prefix?

Thanks!

**`prefix.js`:**

```
const fs = require('fs'); // node.js file system module
config = require('../config.json');
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: 'prefix', // command keyword
    description: 'Changes the bot prefix', // info about command
    group: 'settings', // command group (not displayed in !help [command name])
    aliases: ['botprefix', 'newprefix'], // using these keywords also triggers command
    usage: '[new prefix]', // how command is supposed to be used
    cooldown: '1', // time command cannot be reused after it has been called
    args: true, // are arguments required
execute(message, args) {
  fs.exists("../config.json", function (error) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  })
    ? fs
        .readFile("../config.json", function (error) {
          if (error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
        })
        .toString()
    : config.prefix;

  const newPrefix = args.shift().toString();
  newConfig = {
    token: config.token,
    prefix: newPrefix,
  };

  fs.writeFile("config.json", JSON.stringify(newConfig, null, 2), function (
    error
  ) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
}
```

---

**`config.json`:**

```
{
  "token": "token",
  "prefix": "!"
}
```

Comment: How are you loading the config the first time? Using require or using fs?

Comment: @zer0, Oops. I must've forgot to copy and paste that section of the file when I made the question. I've edited it to include that info. I think i'm using both ways to load the config. Not sure though.

Comment: I don't see where you are loading the config. Yes, you use `fs.readFile` to get the contents of `config.json` in the `prefix` command, but the result is unused.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access data via `require`, it won't be updated later as the function is run once at the beginnign of the project, even if you re-require it. [This](https://blog.codingblocks.com/2018/reading-json-files-in-nodejs-require-vs-fs-readfile/) article can give you a bit more background on it. Basically: Always use `fs.readFile` and you're fine

Comment: You can remove the cache, and the data will be new if you re-require it. I'd stick with fs.readFile personally though.